# Edit text File in unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

```
sname;id;is_up;p_data
"0000";4256;100;"052263"
"006335";5228;100;"00522633"
"ABTEST";1452;100;"1522620  0"
```

How to i Edit the above file in unix to

1. Add 2 lines at the top for title and System date and time
2. Add `;` at the end of each each row
3. Add the End tag at the end of the file

The final file should look like

```
!title
!Time: 2014-12-33
sname;id;is_up;p_data
"0000";4256;100;"052263";
"006335";5228;100;"00522633";
"ABTEST";1452;100;"1522620  0";
!End
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sed` to add `;` to the end of line. If you want to skip the first line from this operation, use the address `1!`.

```
{
    echo '!title'
    echo -n '!Time: '
    date +%Y-%m-%d
    sed '1! s/$/;/' file
    echo '!End'
} > newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `BEGIN` and `END` as this, together with `$0=$0";"` to add a `;` at the end of the lines not being first one:

```
awk -v d="$(date)" '
                    BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d}
                    NR>1{$0=$0";"} 1;
                    END {print "!End"}
                   ' file
```

See output:

```
$ awk -v d="$(date)" 'BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d} NR>1{$0=$0";"} 1; END {print "!End"}' file
!title
!Time:  Wed Apr 30 15:25:53 CEST 2014
sname;id;is_up;p_data
"0000";4256;100;"052263";
"006335";5228;100;"00522633";
"ABTEST";1452;100;"1522620  0";
!End
```

For the `date` format, you should define which one you want. `date` alone prints everything. I would maybe go for:

```
$ date "+%F %T"
2014-04-30 15:41:04
```

Comment: I get the syntax error near line 1 when i run this code.

Comment: What are you exactly running, @user2092096 ?

Comment: awk -v d="$(date)" '
                    BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d}
                    NR>1{$0=$0";"} 1;
                    END {print "!End"}
                   ' sample file.txt

Comment: @user2092096 strange... it works fine to me, on `mawk 1.3.3`. Maybe `date` does not work properly. What if you try `awk -v d="$(date "+%F")" ' BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d} NR>1{$0=$0";"} 1; END {print "!End"}' file` ?

Comment: no luck. i took out the date and its now complaining about the NR function

Comment: @user2092096 mmm, what about changing to `NR>1 {print}` to see if it is matching properly lines after first?

Comment: {
awk -v  '
                    BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d}
                    NR>1 {print};
                    END {print "!End"}
                   '  file.txt
}

Comment: @user2092096 Why are you writing braces around? Also, remove `-v` if you are not using it.

Comment: This works without the date and without NR>1{$0=$0";"} 1. but i now get awk:cant open file

Comment: @user2092096 give a try to this: `awk -v d="$(date)" 'BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d} NR>1{print $0";"; next} {print}; END {print "!End"}' file`

Comment: can i print this to a new file?

Comment: @user2092096 yes,just redirect the command with `> new_file`. For example, `awk -v d="$(date)" 'BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d} NR>1{print $0";"; next} {print}; END {print "!End"}' file > new_file`.

Comment: Thanks. This works without the date.awk '
                    BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d}
                    NR>1{print $0";"; next} {print};
                    END {print "!End"}
                   ' file.txt > new_file.txt

Comment: @user2092096 Nice! In case, you can do `d="2013-05-01";` in bash and then run `awk -v d="$d" ' BEGIN{print "!title"; print "!Time: ", d} NR>1{print $0";"; next} {print}; END {print "!End"} ' file.txt > new_file.txt`.

Comment: thanks. I think awk -v d="$d" is the problem, just looking up the syntax

Comment: @user2092096 so we check the code together and then silently unaccept? facepalm.

Comment: Nope. the date did not work and i had to use the other code. Thanks